# CSS setting height to page size not view port size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a background that hight is currently set to

```
height:100%;
```

This sets the background to the size of the view port bit o would like to set it to the size of the rendered page.

How can I do this?
Will I need to compute the height of the document with JavaScript? or is there a css option available?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you haven't specified any explicit height on the body, the body itself will be the size of the document.

Answer (score 1):

The following state

```
 height:100%;
```

Won't set the height of the background but the height of the element. Please have a look to the css property background-size.

Answer (score 0):

Background will always cover the entire screen background

```
/* background image for mobile portrait mode*/
body.mobile_portrait{
    background-image: url('../multimedia/images/myBackG.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

you could also try background-size: contain; if your background image is of the same height as the device.